# Pascal Triangle recursive program not working

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Here is my code... I am a beginner and appreciate any feed back. My problem I am trying to solve is to print the pascal triangle up to the user imputed row.

```
public class Pascal111 {

  int max;
  int r,c;
  public int pascal(int maxm){
  max=maxm;

  for(int r=0; r<max; r++){
    for (int c=0; c<r; c++){
     populate();}
 }  
  return max;
 }



  public void populate(){
   int[][] array=new int[max][max];
   if (r==0){
     array[0][0]=1;
   }
   else if(c==0){
     array[0][0]=1;
}
else if(c==r){
  array[r][c]=1;;
}
else
  array[r][c]=(array[r-1]+array[c-1]+array[r-1]+array[c]);
 }

}
```

I get the following error....

```
Error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int[]
```

Comment: I know this code is broken in many ways... I am having a hard time understanding recursion if you could bare with me!

Comment: Why do you believe your program is recursive?

Answer (score 1):

```
array[r][c]=(array[r-1]+array[c-1]+array[r-1]+array[c]);
```

is wrong.

`array` is a 2-D array, thus `array[X]` represents a complete row (1-D array). You just can't do binary operation on 1-D arrays and put it on a single element `array[r][c]`.

Instead replace it with

```
array[r][c]=(array[r-1][c-1]+array[r-1][c]);
```

Comment: now the program compiled but I get the following results1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: You also need to change `else if(c==0){ array[0][0]=1;` to `else if(c==0){    array[r][0]=1;`

Comment: I made the adjustment and still get the same input! I also did the same adjustment to the     r==0

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't looked at this closely, one mistake stands out: you have two different variables named `r` and two different variables named `c`.

Here's the relevant parts of your code:

```
public class Pascal111 {

    int r,c;  // (A)

    public int pascal(int maxm) {
        for (int r=0; r<max; r++){    // (B)
            for (int c=0; c<r; c++){  // (B)
                populate();
            }
        }  
        return max;
    }

    public void populate() {
        if (r==0) {
            ... more code that accesses r and c
        }
    }
```

The declaration at (A) declares *instance variables*, because the declaration isn't inside a method.  This means that whenever you create a `Pascal111` object, this object will have fields named `r` and `c`.  They are initialized to 0.

The declarations at (B), since they have `int` keywords on them, declare *new* variables.  These variables are local to the `pascal` method, which means they can be accessed only inside that method.  (Actually, they can be accessed only inside the `for` loops.)  These variables have **no** connection to the instance variables.  They are totally separate.  As you increment these local `r` and `c` variables, the instance variables remain unchanged.  That is, they are still 0.

The `populate` method can't access local variables declared in `pascal`.  So when `populate` refers to `r` and `c`, they are referring to the instance variables.  These are *not* the variables that get incremented in the loop, but rather the instance variables that remain 0.

One way to fix this would be to remove the `int` on the declarations in (B); that would cause `pascal` to increment the instance variables, and then `populate` would use those.  *However, that is the wrong approach.*

The best way to fix these is not to use the instance variables to communicate between `pascal` and `populate`--but rather, to use parameters.  That is:

```
    for (int r=0; r<max; r++){    // (B)
        for (int c=0; c<r; c++){  // (B)
            populate(r, c);
        }
    }
```

and later:

```
public void populate(int r, int c) {
```

Then, when `populate` refers to `r` and `c`, it will refer to the parameters, which are in essence local variables.  The parameters will be the `r` and `c` from `pascal`.  (But you don't have to use the same names for the `pascal` variables and the `populate` parameters.)  After you do this, you'll find that the instance variables are no longer needed at all.  It's always, or almost always, wrong to have instance variables used as loop indexes anyway.

A similar error: You have `array` as a local variable inside `populate`.  This means that you're creating a brand new array every time you call it to set up one array element.  Then, when `populate` returns, `array` can no longer be accessed, so whatever work you've done is lost.

Comment: WOW. This is the best answer yet. This makes allot of sense now. I had seen a previous answer that had been similar to your answer but I could not follow it. Now I completely get it. PS you should be a teacher!

Comment: would you mind if I PM you every now and then for a quick question regarding a problem I encounter?

Comment: Also where would be a good place to put the array a variable so its not getting erased everytime populate is called?

Comment: Regarding the last question: Two decent choices.  (1) Make the array an instance variable and initialize it in the object's constructor.  (2) Declare it in the `pascal` method and pass it as a parameter to `populate`.  An array is a _reference_, so if you do the last, you will still be able to modify it in `populate` even though Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: You could try sending a message, but please be aware I don't have time to answer questions on demand in that manner.  Sorry.